# Media file cannot be found with self.client.get() in Python TestCase

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have an image in `media` folder in my project's root. I can `./manage.py runserver` and access my file successfully via `127.0.0.1:8000/media/img.jpg` url in browser. But the following test fails with `404!=200`. Why?

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_image_shows(self):
         response = self.client.get('/media/img.jpg')
         self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not straightforward nor elegant, but that's the best simple way I found for myself :

1) [Add a static rule](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) in your *urls.py* (it's not enabled in production) :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

2) Enable `DEBUG` for your test case (so that static rule gets enabled):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        assert self.client.get('/medias/something.jpg').status_code == 200
```

You may also want to specify a different `MEDIA_ROOT` for tests not to pollute your dev `MEDIA_ROOT` if you write medias during your tests. An example can be found [on caktus blog](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/06/26/media-root-and-django-tests/).